# Why doesn't PowerShell Where-Object work when passing a variable?

Tags: powershell

The function

```
 function findf {
     Write-Host "Find files that match: $args"
     gci -r | Where-Object { $_.name -match ".*$args.*" }
 }
```

doesn't seem to work.  For example,

```
 findf .exe
```

-- Prints a bunch of stuff not limiting output to EXE files --

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

If I run the same command from the PowerShell command window the command works:

```
 gci -r | Where-Object { $_.name -match ".*.exe.*" }
```

This works and correctly shows me the files that match the *.EXE pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$args` is an object representing a **collection** of arguments.

You should either:

- Reference `$args[0]` to get the string representing the first argument
- Use `param` to define the input parameter like:

.

```
 function findf {
     param ([string]$SeachStr)
     Write-Host "Find files that match: $SeachStr"
     gci -r | Where-Object { $_.name -match ".*$SeachStr.*" }
 }
```

I always advocate using `param` when possible, since you can strongly type your variables like I did in the example.  Otherwise it might be possible to do something confusing like pass an array as a parameter which can cause all sorts of hard-to-trace issues.

Answer (score 2):

$args is not working because the filter is a script block, and runs in it's own scope.  Every scope is initialized with it's own $args, so you cannot implicitly pass $args to a child scope.  Since there's no provision for passing arguments to a filter script block, you have to do something like this:

```
  function findf {
       Write-Host "Find files that match: $args"
       $filter = $args[0]
       gci -r | Where-Object { $_.name -match ".*$filter.*" }
   }
```

Using a named parameter also works, because that will pass implicitly to the child scope.