# In powershell passing variable to where-object not working

Tags: regex, powershell

Its very basic Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
#Make a list of programs depending on Input

get-service  | Where-Object {$_.name -Like $Input}| select-object name,  DisplayName, ServiceType, Status

get-service  | Where-Object {$_.name -Like "Sys*"}| select-object name, DisplayName, ServiceType, Status
```

Now the second get-service works no problem. But the first one does not cooperate with me, it just throws all the services on the server.

I obtain the user input with this:

```
$Input = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your regex'
```

So what is going on here. Where have I gone wrong? And no, I test the variable with a write-host, the string is there. Its not disappearing as far as I can tell.

Comment: no the variable is not empty, I tested for that.

Comment: It not about being empty, but about not using automatic variables.

Comment: @Jason091 `$input` is an automatic variable, it'll get overwritten for every iteration of `Where-Object`. Consider `Get-Service | Where-Object {Write-Host ($_ -eq $input[0]) }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple due to scope.

The solution is to create a filter like shown here:

[Why doesn't PowerShell Where-Object work when passing a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265546/why-doesnt-powershell-where-object-work-when-passing-a-variable)

I just did this:

```
#Make a list of programs depending on Input
$Filter = $Input
get-service  | Where-Object {$_.name -Like $Filter}| select-object name, DisplayName, ServiceType, Status
```