# Where-object passing variable not work on block script

Tags: powershell

My `$var` variable won't work on remote computers. I use filters like in this link [In powershell passing variable to where-object not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964313/in-powershell-passing-variable-to-where-object-not-working). But still my script cant find app from my input.

```
$var = "application" 

Invoke-command -ComputerName $cpu {
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* ,
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*$var*"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your PowerShell version you either have to use the `$using:` prefix on your variable or you have to pass the variable using the `-ArgumentList` parameter. Here an example:

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName $cpu {
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* ,
HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "*$using:var*"}
```