# Variable not passing to Where-Object in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, active-directory, where-object

I have tried the "filter" and "param" options from the post
-- [In powershell passing variable to where-object not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40964313/in-powershell-passing-variable-to-where-object-not-working) -- with no luck. I am fairly new to powershell since I have not used it since 2014. Can anyone assist me in finding out why the `$UName` variable is not being passed to the `Where-Object` command?

```
cls

$UName = Read-Host -Prompt "Name or part of name to search"
Write-Output "Searching for: $UName, please wait"

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {
    $_.name -like "*$UName*" -and 
    $_.company -like "*XYZ Corp*"
}  | select Name, title, company, Country, mailnickname

Pause
```

My only output is:

```
Name or part of name to search: Justin
Searching for: Justin, please wait
Press Enter to continue...
```

I have even tried using `-Contains $UName` and `-Contains "$UName"` yet still get the same results as above.

I have searched, and searched but cannot figure this out. Any assistance would really help!

Comment: If you remove the ```Pause``` or hit ```Enter``` do you see the output? You might be falling foul of an issue where output (implicitly) send to ```Format-Table``` is delayed for 300ms and is being blocked by the ```Pause``` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331305/3156906 for more details...

Comment: Your Where-Object clause is using an undefined variable `$filter`, not `$UName`...

Comment: @Theo - Corrected... In my actual script I had it correct. I have updated this post.

Comment: @mclayton - If I remove the `Pause` or hit `Enter` it just goes to `PS C:\Users\UserName\Documents>`

Comment: Why not use the Active Directory filter instead of `Where-Object` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Now how would I do this? I have change the code to:
`Get-ADUser -Filter { $_.name -Contains "$UName" -and $_.company -like "*XYZ Corp*"` and it errors out:
Get-ADUser : Variable: '_' found in expression: $_.name is not defined.
At C:\Users\K90013780\Documents\Get User Details By Name.ps1:6 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Mic 
   rosoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: `$_.company -like "*XYZ Corp*"` will this be a hardcoded value part of your query? Using the filter is not that hard, tho I recommend `-LDAPFilter` instead of `-Filter`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Yes `$_.company -like "*XYZ Corp*"` is hard coded. I will look into `LDAPFilter` and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script can be simplified as follows, you really shouldn't query all Domain Users (`-Filter *`) to then filter them with PowerShell (`Where-Object`). Instead, you should use the [Active Directory Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)). Same goes for querying all users properties (`-Properties *`) when you actually only need some of them (`Name, title, company, Country, mailnickname`).

```bash
# using Trim() to remove any excess whitespace (trailing and leading)
$UName = (Read-Host -Prompt "Name or part of name to search").Trim()
# if there was no input or input was purely whitespace
if(-not $UName) {
    # exit this script
    return
}

# if input was valid
Write-Output "Searching for: $UName, please wait"

# try to search for the user
$props = 'Name', 'title', 'company', 'Country', 'mailnickname'
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(name=*$UName*)(company=*XYZ Corp*))" -Properties $props |
    Select-Object $props | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! after 9 years out of scripting I would have never thought of this solution!